# Issues with SQL Server 2012 creating new database diagram

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise and while I'm trying to make a new database diagram, I get this error :

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

I've tried reinstalling SQL Server but it didn't work.

Note: I installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and then I uninstalled it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this post](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/730985/smss-crashes-when-creating-new-database-diagram#) and go to workarounds.

On my machine, I have `VS2012`, `SQL2008`, and `SQL2012`. At one point I had installed `VS2013`, which updated the `dlls` in the following folders (mentioned by other users) to the `VS2013` versions. After uninstalling `VS2013`, they remained and caused the conflict. In order to fix it I simply backed up and deleted all of the files in these locations:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\dsref80.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\
```

Then ran a repair of `VS2012`, which restored the `dlls` to the proper version. Everything is working smoothly now and I am able to create and open DB diagrams.

Also you have details [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc/visual-studio-database-tools-error?forum=vstsdb).

Comment: Thanks alot
I've problem
Now I don't have VS2012 and I just installed Ms SQL server and I don't have VS2012 so I can repair nothing What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Uninstall the reinstall sql server.

Comment: It's a link that I found in my searches 

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa9df00f-49ba-4345-b036-423ae30a5d47/problem-to-create-new-database-diagram-in-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-for-sql-server?forum=sqlexpress

but does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by replacing files at this folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\

One of my friends gave me the required files